# How do I generate a seven digit random number which is itself divisible by seven

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, generator

I am working on a program, and all of the parts work perfectly except one, that part is supposed to generate a seven digit random number which is divisible by 7.

I am aware that there are similiar questions to mine, but I did not find my anwser within them, and despite trying I was myself only capable of somethimes generating such a number.

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Couldn't you just generate any random number (or at least between 1 and 306783378) and then multiply that result by 7?

Comment: Or, since you've updated your question, a random number between 142,858 and 1,428,571 and then multiply that by 7.

Comment: For your intended task, do you consider `0000007` or `0777777` as random seven digit numbers? or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulo function (see `set /?`):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "number=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "number=%number:~0,7%"
set /a remainder=number %% 7
if %remainder% equ 0 (
  echo %number% is a multiple of 7
) else (
  echo %number% divided by 7 gives a rest of %remainder%
)
```

Just in case, leading zero(s) is/are ok or even desired as a possibility:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "number=%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%"
set "number=%number:~-7%"
set /a remainder=7%number% %% 7
if %remainder% equ 0 (
  echo %number% is a multiple of 7
) else (
  echo %number% divided by 7 gives a rest of %remainder%
)
```

Comment: @furybowser - I'm a little surprised that you accepted this answer since it doesn't guarantee that the result has 7 digits.

Comment: @SomethingDark: I considered this as trivial (and assumed, OP already has a 7digit number and only wanted to check if it is a multiple of 7), but to do it correctly, I edited my answer.

Comment: But you could end up with the 7 digit number beginning with a 0.

Comment: @Squashman yes, I dreamt about that tonight. Edited.

Comment: Generate a random number, divide by 7, round down to the nearest integer, and multiply by 7.

Comment: @3Dave: like `set /a num=78/7*7` - outputs `77`, because `cmd` can only handle 32bit-integers (no need to "round down" - fractions are ignored)

Comment: @SomethingDark So firstly, I did not notice that, secondly, sorry for late reply, but I was kind of inactive on this site until now, and thirdly, I gave up on my program.
Edit: Should I change my accepted anwser?

Comment: @furybowser I corrected the issue mentioned by SomethingDark a few minutes later, so it now always gives 7 digits. You should accept the answer that solves your issues best (in *your* opinion) and helped you most to understand. Others may upvote other answers when *they*  think it's better.  (You are not supposed to guess, which answer is the "academical best" one - usually, there is no such thing). For example, Comp's answer has better randomness, but it's slower.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different method, which is designed to propagate a variable, named `D7` with a seven digit value, which when divided by seven will return an exact integer:

This first example allows for leading `0`'s in the resulting value.

```sh
Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "D7="
For /L %%G In (0 1 9) Do For %%H In (
    %Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%
) Do (Set /A D7 = 7%%H%%G %% 7
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & If !D7! Equ 0 (EndLocal
        Set "D7=%%H%%G"
        GoTo :Next))
:Next
Set D7
Pause
```

*Please note: It is possible that the resulting value could be `0000000` because leading `0`'s are allowed and `0` is divisible by every integer.*

---

If you do not want to have leading `0`'s then a very small adaptation is needed:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "D7="
For /L %%G In (1 1 9) Do For %%H In (
    %Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%%Random:~-1%
) Do (Set /A D7 = %%G%%H %% 7
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & If !D7! Equ 0 (EndLocal
        Set "D7=%%G%%H"
        GoTo :Next))
:Next
Set D7
Pause
```